# how to avoid shared module dependency in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

How do I deal with common dependencies within a project?

Lets say I make a package, `pack`, with some modules, `mod1` and `mod2`.  All of the modules need to use some common external modules.  For example:

```
mod1.py:
import sys
import numpy    
# define stuff

mod2.py:
import numpy
# define more stuff
```

I also want to use the same external modules in my main code:

```
main.py:
import sys
import numpy
import pack
# do the stuff
```

In this situation I appear to have multiple copies of `numpy` and `sys` loaded i.e.:

```
numpy
pack.mod1.numpy
pack.mod2.numpy
```

This seems bad.  Do I really have multiple `numpy`s or do I have one `numpy` with three names?  Is there a way to avoid this sort of thing?  What is the best practice in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to worry, the code in the modules get executed only once when it is imported by your first module. When you import it in the second module, you just get a 'pointer' to the already cached module.

Quick demonstration:

```
# mod1.py
print 'starting mod1'
import mod3
print 'finished mod1'

# mod2.py
print 'starting mod2'
import mod3
print 'finished mod2'

# mod3.py
print 'in mod3'
```

Result:

```
In [2]: import mod1
starting mod1
in mod3
finished mod1

In [3]: import mod2
starting mod2
finished mod2
```

Comment: Additionally, I believe the multiple module references only become significant if you start `reload`ing modules. In many ways, Python module imports are similar to `import` in Java or `using` in C#.